# Recursive method deleting all occurrences

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

How can I create a recursive method that takes Singly linked list and an element as parameters
then deletes all occurrences of that element from the list, starting from the current element?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

why should it be recursive?
as i have not much information, let's just guess the generic type of your list is "String"... (could be anything else).

```
LinkedList<String> removeObjects(LinkedList<String> inputList, String stringToRemove) {
    LinkedList<String> output = inputList;
    if (output.contains(stringToRemove)) {
        output.remove(stringToRemove);
        return removeObjects(output, stringToRemove);
    } else return output;
}
```